# how to make the progress bar label flow out of the bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
 span:hover, span:active{
 font-size: 150%;
 color: black;
 text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.8;
  overflow:visible;
 }
 span{
 overflow:visible;
 }
 
 </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col col-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 col-offset-2 text-center">
   <h5>MVC architecture</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8 col-offset-2">
   <div class="progress" >
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 46.66%; margin-left: 33.33%; height: 60px;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
     <span>10 to 24 LPA</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>   
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 col-offset-2 text-center">
      <h5>MS-Access</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 col-offset-2">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 3.63%; margin-left: 2%; height: 40px;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
          <span>0.6 to 1.5 LPA</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[The text in the progress bar doesn't fit in it and it is clipped. When hovered over the text, its font size increases but the text will remain hidden. What is the solution?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLilC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the text will try to fit inside your progressbar, which is very tide. So you can use `position: absolute;`

```css
span:hover,
span:active {
  font-size: 150%;
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.8;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
}

span {
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.centered{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 8px 0 0 -20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 col-offset-2 text-center">
      <h5>MS-Access</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 col-offset-2">
     <span class="text-center centered">0.6 to 1.5 LPA</span>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 3.63%; height: 40px;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: But the text begins from the center, and is flowing to the right...which doesn't look very well. I'm looking for all possible solutions to make it look good, either inside or outside of the progress bar.

Comment: @SahithiPonangi check the updated one, also if want a better looking and dynamic progress bar, you can find a lot here:
https://codepen.io/search/pens/?q=progress%20bar&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

Comment: But i cant use center in htlm5. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @SahithiPonangi yes

Answer (score 0):

try this with no absolute position

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
 span:hover, span:active{
 font-size: 100%;
 color: black;
 
 }
 .progress> .progress-bar> span{
 overflow:visible;
  margin-top:45%;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  color:red;
  min-width:100px
  
 }
 
 </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 col-offset-2 text-center">
      <h5>MS-Access</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 col-offset-2">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 3.63%; margin-left: 2%; height: 40px;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
          <span>0.6 to 1.5 LPA</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <div class="row">
   <div class="col col-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 col-offset-2 text-center">
    <h5>MVC architecture</h5>
   </div>
   <div class="col-8 col-offset-2">
    <div class="progress" >
     <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 46.66%; margin-left: 33.33%; height: 60px;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <span>10 to 24 LPA</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>   
  </div>

Comment: If i use the above code in the body, i cant see the text

Comment: change the value for margin-top and see there after